# How to sum up multiple columns in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

How to sum the 4 columns in elastic search.
Example:

```
 A B C 
 1 1 1 
 1 2 2
```

Sum of `A = 2`, Sum of `B = 3`, Sum of `C = 3` and Sum of `total(A,B,C) = 8`.

How to get the sum?
I have done an aggregation query but it is throwing me `Unexpected token START_ARRAY`

```
 {
  "aggs": {
    "total_count": {
      "sum": {
        "base_count": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "cse_licenseactivated_base_count"
          }
        },
        "malware_count": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "cse_licenseactivated_malware_count"
          }
        },
        "threat_count": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "cse_licenseactivated_threat_count"
          }
        },
        "urlfiltering_count": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "cse_licenseactivated_urlfiltering_count"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a script like this:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "total_count": {
      "sum": {
         "source": "doc.cse_licenseactivated_base_count.value + doc.cse_licenseactivated_malware_count.value + doc.cse_licenseactivated_threat_count.value + doc.cse_licenseactivated_urlfiltering_count.value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can also sum up all those fields at indexing time and store the sum in another fields called `cse_licenseactivated_total_count`, which is a better way to do it